# Use JMeter Variable in Groovy Code

Tags: variables, groovy, jmeter, assertion

I have an Config Element in JMeter, Especially User Defined Variables.

I have the variable "user" with the value "Justin",  How can I use this variable in the groovy code (of an JSR223 Assertion)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several of getting it:

1. Given you pass the variable to the JSR223 Assertion script via "Parameters" section you can access it as `Parameters` which contains the full string passed in the "Parameters" section
2. Given you pass the variable to the JSR223 Assertion script via "Parameters" section you can access it as `args[0]` (if you pass more than one variable separated by spaces you will be able to refer 2nd variable as `args[1]`, 3rd as `args[2]`, etc.
3. You can access it as `vars.get('user')` where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
4. You can access it as `vars['user']` - basically the same as point 3 but uses some [Groovy Syntax Sugar](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
5. You can access it as `ctx.getVariables().get('user')` - where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html) class instance just in case (in some test elements `vars` shorthand is not available)

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Get Variable Value]

Comment: Note: the variable has to be set somewhere. I set it by adding a User Defined Variable in the Test Plan section. I set the Name to user and the value to Justin to repeat this example.

Answer (score 3):

Any JSR223 element including Assertion have few variables it can use out of the box.

One of the variable is `vars` which is basically a map of JMeter stored variables.

User Defined Variables row is creating a JMeter variable, so you can get your value Justin in JSR223 using `vars.get("user")`